# flutterToast problems when upgrading SDK

Tags: flutter, toast

as per Google new requirements to upgrade the target SDK to 33 minimum, I started doing this & I am getting the same error in most of my Apps & I can't resolve it, please help, the error is
'''A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

```
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.'''
```

I am sure that the namespace is added in my '''build.gradle''', also I tried to update the flutterToast to 8.2.2 but the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the repo code, it seems that it has been fixed but not released to pub server. You can use these lines for your pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  fluttertoast:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast.git
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it really worked for flutter toast but now I have another issue with another plugin ```:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer```

Comment: Oops, another new issue. There is an issue open regarding [syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer#issue1321](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets/issues/1321)